# My <span> structure gets nested while running

Tags: html

I have the following code in Visual studio

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
  <div class="icon">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </div>
 <h3> Navigation</h3>
</a>
```

But while running it, it looks like this in the browser:

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
  <div class="icon">
    <span class="icon-bar">
    <span class="icon-bar">
    <span class="icon-bar">
    </span></span></span>
  </div>
<h3> Navigation</h3>
</a>
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: i`m not sure, but try write like this
<span class="icon-bar">&nbsp;</span>

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you have in the Visual Studio?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Added it

Comment: as @LeoKomarov said... maybe cause of emoty tags

Comment: Yeah, try adding a non-breaking space.

Comment: Thank you @LeoKomarov! That worked now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Leo said and with my personal experience, can you try adding:

```
<span class="icon-bar">&nbsp;</span>
<span class="icon-bar">&nbsp;</span>
<span class="icon-bar">&nbsp;</span>
```

And also, would you please remove the `<h3>` from inside of the `<a>`?

To add to it, you can give something like to hide the text completely:

```
.icon-bar {overflow: hidden; text-indent: -100%;}
```